# AngularJS v2.login is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried many solutions from SO, but none of them works. So, I have a html form defined like so:

```
//views/login.html
<form name="form" ng-submit="login()" role="form">
...
</form>
```

In my app.js file, I have this code:

```
...
$routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
    })
```

And finally, my login controller is defined like so:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('frontendApp')
    .controller('LoginCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.login = function() {
            console.log("Test it");
        };
    }]);
```

However, when I click on submit button, I get this error message:

> v2.login is not a function

I tried to edit form definition like so:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="LoginCtrl.login()" role="form">
```

but to no avail. So, what may be wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you post your full html where you have used the module and controller?

Comment: I published it here - https://github.com/chupacabra007/otus/tree/master/frontend/app

Comment: `app.js` is inside `scripts` folder, `controllers` are inside `scripts/controllers` folder, `login.html` is inside `views` folder. Hope it will help.

Comment: Can you try moving the scripts in the head tag because you are bootstrapping the angular application before even angularjs and the app.js is loaded

Comment: In a moment. Though, I just followed some tutorials.

Comment: By scripts you mean all the scripts except app.js and controllers?

Comment: no i mean every script in the same order as they are now

Comment: I tried it and got the very same error message.

Comment: have you used `ng-controller=LoginCtrl` in your html page?I don't see it . if you don't include it then the function won't be found by angular in that scope.

Comment: Where should I put it? In what tag? Can you please a bit elaborate on this? In tutorials, that I've used, I see no mentioning of ng-controller. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, it works! Thank you, sir! It seems like I've used outdated tutorials.

Comment: perfect I have just posted it as answer, can you please accept it?

Comment: Please check my full answer

Comment: Yes, indeed!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `ng-controller` with the same controller name or alias `login` in your login.html page where you are using the `login()` function on `ng-submit` like below

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
<div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
<form name="form" ng-submit="login()" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="username" required />
        <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" required />
        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
        <img ng-if="dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"/>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

you can also use `ng-controller="login"` as you have defined it as alias `controllerAs: 'login'` in your app.js.